# To print odd and even via two classes implements Runnable, one is having odd number logic and another having even number logic

Tags: java, multithreading

Tried to print odd number via PrintOddClass and even via PrintEvenClass
I used to start those two threads via PrintOddEvenNumberTwoThreads but not able to achieve them.
Like
1
2
3
4 so on
After printing 1 2 it goes to a deadlock state I guess.

Used join() method also but it is of no use.
I want to achieve that via this way only.

```
public class PrintOddEvenNumberTwoThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int N = 20;
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new PrintOddNumber(N), "OddThread");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new PrintEvenNumber(N), "EvenThread");
        
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class PrintOddNumber implements Runnable {
    private int limit;
    private int num = 1;
    
    public PrintOddNumber(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            while(num < limit) {
                if(num % 2 != 0) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(num);
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                num++;
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

class PrintEvenNumber implements Runnable {
    private int limit;
    private int num = 1;
    
    public PrintEvenNumber(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            while(num < limit) {
                if(num % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(num);
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                num++;
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you just want use two thread alternate print like 1(Thread1) ->2(Thread2)->3(Thread1)->4(Thread2)?

Comment: @TongChen yes the output should be _oddThread -> 1 evenThread -> 2_ like this

Comment: You should know that this assignment is a Bad Example of how to use threads. The entire point of threads is, to let different activities in a program happen _concurrently_ with one another (i.e., things happen in no particular order or, at worst, in a loosely controlled order.) There is no concurrency if you force the threads to take turns. There is no benefit—none at all—to using threads in the way that your instructor has asked you to do. The assignment will teach you how to do certain things, but it gives you completely the wrong message about when or why do do those things.